# Problem with do if command in spss: "expression is incomplete"

Tags: spss

I would like to compute in `spss` a multiple `if` condition. My data looks like this:

```
DO IF (A<75 & DN<75).
COMPUTE AD=0.
else if (A=75 & DN<75).
COMPUTE AD=(A-75). 
else if (A<75 & DN=75).
COMPUTE AD=(DN-75). 
else if (A=75 & DN=75).
COMPUTE AD=[(A-75)+(DN-75)].
END IF.
EXECUTE.
```

It gives me an error at the last compute command, saying:

```
The expression is incomplete.  Check for missing operands, invalid operators, 
unmatched parentheses or excessive string length. 
Execution of this command stops.
```

Can anyone tell me please how should I formulate the equation in order to be acceptable to `spss`?

Comment: I think if you just change these "[...]" into "(...)" everything should work. So: `compute AD=( (A-75)+(DN-75) ).`

Answer (score 0):

Right, square and curly brackets are not allowed in COMPUTE expressions, only parentheses. Spaces in between nested parentheses are allowed, but not required.